# JBoss EAP 6.2 - How to use server-name in logging configuration in domain.xml

Tags: logging, jboss, jboss-eap-6

### Quick context:

- I Have two hosts on which I have jboss eap 6.2.
- In each host.xml I have defined 2 servers (say Host1Server1, Host1Server2, Host2Server1, Host2Server2).
- All these 4 servers are part of same server group (say myServerGroup)
- myServerGroup uses profile full-ha
- All the configuration (JVM settings, deployment etc) is in domain.xml on Host1
- On Host2, the domain.xml doesn't exist (it is renamed to domain.xml.dont.use)
- I start the servers by using domain.sh on each host (not standalone.sh) (On host2, the domain.sh is passed a property file using -P argument and the property file sets the property jboss.domain.master.address to point to Host1.

### The Problem Statement:

What I want to achieve is that the log files for these servers are written in same folder and the file name should have the server name in it. For example ...

```
/my/logdir/Host1Server1.log
/my/logdir/Host1Server2.log
/my/logdir/Host2Server1.log
/my/logdir/Host2Server2.log
```

I do not know how to make this happen. Currently in the domain.xml on Host1, under profile full-ha, the logging is defined as

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.3">
  <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
  <formatter>
    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
  </formatter>
  <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
  <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
  <append value="true"/>
</periodic-rotating-file-handler>
...
...
```

What I would like to do ideally is to have it look something like ...

```
  ...
  <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="${jboss.server.name}.log"/>
  ...
```

but when I do that, the server doesn't start -- it doesn't recognize the jboss.server.name property.

Is there any way to handle this?

Thanks in advance.

-- Parag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the `jboss.server.name` system property is set after logging is configured.

What you could do is change the `directory-grouping` attribute on the `host` resource to `by-type`. This will put the logs in the `$JBOSS_HOME/domain/logs/${jboss.server.name}` directory.

```
domain/log/
├── host-controller.log
├── process-controller.log
└── servers
    ├── server-one
    │   └── server.log
    └── server-two
        └── server.log
```

To update the attribute in CLI use the following operation on the default host (master).

```
/host=master:write-attribute(name=directory-grouping,value=by-type)
```

You'll then need to restart the server. You're logs should now all be in the log directory though under a new directory for each server.

If you read the resource in CLI for the `host=*` resource you'll see the following description.

```
"directory-grouping" => {
    "type" => STRING,
    "description" => "Describes how the writable directories for servers managed by this host controller should be organized. The default value, 'by-server', indicates each server's writable directories should be grouped under the server's name in the domain/servers directory. The alternative, 'by-type' indicates each server's writable directories should be grouped based on their \"type\" (i.e. \"data\", \"log\", \"tmp\") with directories of a given type for all servers appearing in the domain level directory for that type, e.g. domain/data/servers/server-name.",
    "expressions-allowed" => true,
    "nillable" => true,
    "default" => "by-server",
    "allowed" => [
        "by-type",
        "by-server"
    ],
    "access-type" => "read-write",
    "storage" => "configuration",
    "restart-required" => "all-services"
}
```

Comment: James, this worked well for me. Thanks a lot.
Is there any way for me to keep them in the same directory? That is, is there a way to have them in the same directory with different name (server name being part of the name).

Comment: Not that I can think of. They only way the `jboss.server.name` property would work is if there was a change made to the `org.jboss.as.host.controller.ManagedServerBootCmdFactory` which is an internal class. While I doubt this would happen in EAP 6, you can file a feature request for [WildFly](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY) which could make it into EAP 7.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options to evaluate would be to find a way to override the log file names in startup script for the individual servers. There are few parameters that you can set as JVM argument and they should take precedence over what is configured in domain.xml or host.xml for that matter.

Customize the default log4j.properties/logging.properties and provide that to JVM by editing run.sh or can provide that as command line parameter. e.g.

```
run.bat -Dlogging.configuration=file:./logging.properties
```

And in logging.properties, you can change the following entry to have appropriate log file

```
handler.FILE.fileName=your/log/directory/<server.log>
```

**References:**

https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossBootLogging

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/233393

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/250554

Disclaimer: Long time I have not worked with JBoss and I did not try any of the above steps :)